# Правильно ли я понял смысл реализации mvp

Tags: android, mvp

У меня был большой класс Browser и с помощью mvp я попытался вынести логику за пределы этого класса. И вот что у меня получилось.

1. Я создал Интерфейс BrowserContrack

   ```
     interface BrowserContrack {

           interface MenuBrowser{
               fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean
               fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean
           }

           interface Vk {
               fun authorization(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)
           }

           interface BrowserLogic{
               fun logicWebView(webView: WebView, progressBar: ProgressBar)
           }
       }
   ```

   Я также решил логику разбить на класс, но сейчас понимаю что это не лучший вариант из-за сложности обмена данными между ними. Будет проще воспользоваться быстрым поиском нужной функции.
2. Реализовал класс посредник, *как я это сейчас понимаю*.

   ```
   class MenuPresenter(activity: AppCompatActivity,
                   context: Context,
                   webView: WebView) : BrowserContrack.MenuBrowser {

   val myMenu: MyMenu = MyMenu(activity, context, webView)

   override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
       return myMenu.menuCreateOptions(menu)
   }

   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
      return myMenu.menuOptionsItemSelected(item)
   } }
   ```
3. Всю логику я прописал в классе MyMenu

```
class MyMenu(val activity: AppCompatActivity, val context: Context, val webView: WebView) {

    private var SearchGlobalItem : MenuItem? = null

    fun menuCreateOptions(menu: Menu?) : Boolean{
        activity.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_browser, menu)
        SearchGlobalItem = menu?.findItem(R.id.goBack)
        return true
    }

    fun menuOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) : Boolean{

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.backward -> {
                //Вернуться домой
                activity.startActivity(Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java))
                return true
            }
            R.id.goBack -> {
                System.out.println("Сработала кнопка домой....")
                webView.goBack() //Перейти назад
                return true
            }
            R.id.forward -> {
                webView.goForward() //Перейти вперад истории webview
                return true
            }
            R.id.m_vk -> {
                Connect(context, activity).checkAuthorization(
                        webView.title,
                        "Что-то интересное...",
                        webView.url
                )
                return true
            }
            else -> return activity.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

4. Вызываю реализацию меню непосредственно в класс BrowserActivity.

```
class BrowserActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    lateinit var mMenuPresenter: MenuPresenter
    lateinit var mWebView : WebView
    lateinit var mProgressBar: ProgressBar

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.m_browser)

        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.mbrowser)
        //mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
        //BrowserPresenter().logicWebView(mWebView, mProgressBar)

        // Здесь вызываю, и передаю нужные компоненты.
        mMenuPresenter = MenuPresenter(this, this, mWebView)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
       return mMenuPresenter.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return mMenuPresenter.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Вопрос в том, **правильно ли я понял суть mvp**? Потому что я только начал его изучать, а так-же хотелось узнать про Dagger 2, как бы он мне смог помочь в данный момент, можно вкратце.

Comment: контекст можно не передавать, он и есть активити

Comment: не правильно поняли, хотя бы потому, что презентер не должен знать ничего об вашей активити (view) и контексте. Презентер вообще не должен знать, что работает в среде Android, в идеале, презентер можно без изменений применить в любой другой системе, где будет view, которая имплементирует такой же интерфейс. В вашем случае, вы разбили один большой класс на несколько маленьких, вот и все.

Comment: @Flippy спасибо

Comment: @mit но я же тогда не смогу работать с Android компонентами, если не передам контекст. Я взял в качестве примера вот этот ресурс https://github.com/quangctkm9207/hello-mvp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/quangnguyen/hellomvp

Comment: @CegreiUlanov вы в презентер должны передавать контракт (интерфейс) который имплементируетт ваша активити (view), никаких реализаций в презентер не должно передаваться, только абстракции, т.е. интерфейсы, таким образом у вас не будет жестской связи между view и present слоем, не смотрел вашу ссылку, но думаю, что там не совсем верно все описано, если вы в презентер передаете объект view

Comment: @CegreiUlanov вам нужно создать еще один интерфейс, который будет имплементировать ваша активити. Вот этот интерфейс и передавайте в презентер, и в презентере вызываете соответствующие методы этого интерфейса, тогда вам не понадобится в презентере ни контекст, ни активити

Comment: @mit Если я вас правильно понял. [здесь](https://andhradroid.wordpress.com/2015/04/04/mvp-pattern-in-android/) реализован ваш подход. Откройте пожалуйста. А вот разбиенье логики по классам, как я это сделал, это актуально? Только вот не прибегая к интерфейсам, контрактам, презентаторами, а просто раскидать по классам? А уже с потом реализовать примерный mvp как показано на сайте и управлять ими.